# Is there any nonnegative $u\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $-\Delta u=1$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Is there any nonnegative $u\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with $\Delta u=-1$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

I think not, but how can we prove it? Let's assume that such a solution exists. Let $R>0$ and $B_R:=B_R(0)$ denote the open ball around $0\in\mathbb{R}^n$ with radius $R>0$. It's easy to verify that $$u(r):=\frac{R^2-r^2}{2n}\;\;\;\text{for }r\in [0,R]$$ is the (uniquely determined) radial solution of $$\left\{\begin{matrix}-\Delta u_R&=&1&\text{in}&B_R\\ u&=&0&\text{on}&\partial B_R\end{matrix}\right.$$ By the *comparison theorem* we've got $$u\ge u_R\;\;\;\text{in }B_R\tag{1}$$ Maybe we can find a contradiction to $(1)$.

---

I've tried the following: Let $w:=u_R-u$ in $B_R$. Then, $$\Delta w=0,$$ i.e. $w$ is harmonic in $B_R$. Now, the *weak maximum principle* yields $$\max_{\overline{B}_R}w=\max_{\partial B_R}w=\max_{\partial B_R}u\tag{2}$$ However, I'm unable to use $(2)$ to find a contradiction. Maybe we need to take advantage of the explicit shape of $u_R$, but I don't know how to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v(x) = x_1^2 + \cdots +x_n^2$.  Then $v \ge 0$ and $\Delta v = 2n$. If $u \ge 0$ and $\Delta u = -1$ then $u + v/2n \ge 0$ and $\Delta(u + v/2n) = 0$. A nonnegative harmonic function is constant, so that $u + v/2n = C$ for some constant $C$. This leads rather quickly to a contradiction since $v(x) \to \infty$ as $|x| \to \infty$.

Comment: That is waaaay too elegant. :) Nice.

Comment: Could you please explain why a nonnegative harmonic function is constant?

Comment: It is the real part of an entire function.

Comment: So, you're referring to Liouville's theorem, right? As you've shown, $w:=u+v/(2n)$ is bounded below by $0$. In order to use the theorem, we need the boundedness from above too, right? So, what am I missing?

Comment: If $f$ is an entire function whose real part is nonnegative, you must have $|f(z) + 1| \ge 1$ for all $z$. Can you show that makes $f$ constant?

Comment: I was able to show it by considering $e^{-f}$.

Comment: Great. It's interesting how many ways Liouville's theorem can be applied.